# Xamarin Forms - Get a 3D effect for the map

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps

My question is pretty simple, but I couldn't be able to find anything about, maybe I didn't used the good key-words..

I'm making an app and I would like to know if it's possible to have a map such as "Pokemon Go" or "Waze"? Furthermore, I'm wondering if a switch is possible like the Waze's one? When you unzoom, it comes back to a 2D map view.

Thank for any help or information about it !

Comment: I think the best place to start would be https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/ or if you are just looking to use waze, try looking at the waze API https://www.waze.com/about/dev

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a custom Map renderer to achieve this 3D look, since Forms does not expose the camera API's. This works by attaching a camera to the map view. The following examples should do the job. You will have to play with the exact settings to achieve the look you require.

**On iOS**

You can attach a camera to a `MKMapView` like this:

```
// Create the camera
MKMapCamera camera = new MKMapCamera();
camera.Pitch = 80;
camera.Altitude = 100;
camera.Heading = 90;

// Attach the camera
map.SetCamera(camera, false);
```

**On Android**

Attach a camera to `GoogleMap` like this:

```
// Create the camera
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                  .Target(location)
                                                  .Tilt(45)
                                                  .Zoom(10)
                                                  .Bearing(0)
                                                  .Build();
// Convert to an update object
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

// Attach the camera
map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate); // map is of type GoogleMap
```

For more info [visit the Android docs on camera position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#the_camera_position)

**On UWP**

You can use the `DesiredPitch` property to achieve a similar look. See the documentation on [configuring a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#configure-the-map).

As for the switch, you can subscribe to events to remove or add the angle of the cameras when they reach a specific treshold.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, interesting since I didn't where to start from. Do you think a such solution would also work with UWP?

Comment: I've updated the answer for UWP. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Let me try once I come back in my country in 2weeks, so I'll be able to work, my laptop got broken... Thank !